# The Spyc library could not be found - Drupal 7 web services

Tags: drupal

I'm setting up a REST server with web services on Drupal 7. I'm getting the error report:

> The Spyc library could not be found

I downloaded the `Spyc.php` library (from https://github.com/mustangostang/spyc) and uploaded it to:

> /sites/all/modules/services/servers/rest_server/lib/

And also tried putting it in `/servers/rest_server/lib/Spyc/`, but I still get the error.

Comment: Try with a low case 's' in 'spyc.php'. According to the REAMDE.txt file, you should have the library in /sites/all/modules/services//servers/rest_server/lib/spyc.php

Answer (score 5):

The answer above appears to be out of date.

Downloading spyc from the link above and placing in sites/all/libraries/spyc takes care of the problem. No changes to capitalization are necessary.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Now the complete path is /sites/all/libraries/spyc/spyc.php. It is working now.

Answer (score 3):

The Services module documentation is not accurate!

*...Once downloaded you need to add spyc.php to the rest_server/lib folder which exists under
the location you have installed services in.*

You simply need to create a spyc folder containing spyc.php and place it in the sites/all/libraries, as should be expected with any external libraries.